# How to export font-awesome svg icons as a base64 url?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, base64, font-awesome

As I know, we can encode a svg image to a base64 string and use it as a url in a html document, like the below.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"/>
```

So Now I want to make a base64 url of the icons in the FontAwesome library.

How can I do it?

Please help.

Comment: There are online Base64 encoders that you can copy the SVG text into and have it converted.  I assume you are only using a small number of icons, so doing it manually is not going to be a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font Squirrel has options for doing this. Choose the expert option after uploading the font(s)
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Note there are drawbacks to this, see https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/294

Comment: I's not clear how to get it. Can you make a more clear example?

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you won't be able to use it in an url. after uploading your font and choosing the expert option there is a section titled CSS with options to Base64 Encode within a CSS file. It will generate a css file with the "CSS Filename" setting. There are alot of options and can't say I've had a need to try most of them.